# Qt always doubleclick on tablet

Tags: click, touch, tablet, qt5

I have a problem with my tablet (Dell windows 8) running a Qt GUI.
On my PC, the program runs fine, everything works as i expect it to do. But when i run the app on the tablet, Qt seems to interprete a normal touch "klick" as a double tap. Buttons just get clicked twice with almost no delay. Also i get a lot of "cannot accessible interface for object..." messages, but it turned out to be a bug in Qt, yet unresolved. Had anybody similar problems when using Qt on touch devices?

thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm using all sort of hacks to try and make it work. Did you ever found out what the problem was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i might have found the solution. It had nothing to do with the Tablet IMHO.

The problem solved itself when i replaced all static QT members (e.G. Buttons and other Clickable widgets) with dynamically allocated ones.

I had:

```
QPushButton m_oMainButton;
```

and now:

```
QPushButton * m_poMainButton
```

This resolved the problem. I think it has to do with giving Layouts and other QT managers the ownership over my buttons. I never really found out why that happended, but it solved it.